# Is it possible to load UIStackView arrangedSubviews after init

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `View` which contains a `UIStackView`, this `UIStackView` `arrangedSubviews` is an array of `UIButtons`. What happens is that when I'm on `ViewDidLoad` of my `ViewController`, I set an array of `UIButtons` like this:

`let buttons = [button1, button2, button3, button4]`

The number of buttons can vary from 1 to 4.
On the `View` file I have a variable with `didSet`, on that `didSet` I set an array in the view to have the contents of the `buttons` array.
The problem is that the `didSet` happens after the `View's` `init()`, so when I setup the `UIStackView`, the array is an empty array.

Is there a way to make the view to set the UIStackView again after the didSet, so I will have the array I need?

This is my View with the didSet and the array:

```
class ProductDetailView: UIView {

   var productViewModel: ProductDetailViewModel? {
      didSet {
         self.quantityButtons = self.productViewModel?.quantityOptions ?? [] <--- This is where I set the buttons array.
      }
  }

  //MARK: - Properties 
  var quantityButtons: [UIButton] = [] //TODO: This should be a custom button.
}
```

This is my UIStackView:

```
private lazy var quantitiesStack: UIStackView = {
    let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: self.quantityButtons)
    stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stack.axis = .horizontal
    stack.distribution = .fillEqually
    stack.spacing = 2.0

    return stack
}()
```

If it is not possible, how should I approach this issue? how can I have the populated array when I need it?

EDIT: I also tried this approach:

```
var quantityButtons: [UIButton] {
    return productViewModel?.quantityOptions ?? []
}
```

still got an empty array.

Comment: What you're trying to do should work, Where are you adding the buttons as arranged subviews to your stackView?

Comment: I'm setting the buttons from viewModel to the quantityButtons variable. the arrangedSubviews in the quantitiesStack is using quantityButtons.

Comment: You need to show that code because that is the problem here. Modify your didSet to actually add the views to the stackView and it will work. Right now it looks like setting quantityButtons does nothing and they need to be added to the stackView after this is set.

Comment: @DoesData thanks, but the didSet is happening after the init() in the view. so If I try and add the buttons to it in the didSet I will crash, also, I don't have a way to add the views because the arrangedSubivews are read only, no? I tried and the quantityButtons does get set, but just after the init() as the didSet happens after the init(), that's why I'm trying to somehow force the stack to load again or something. I tried setNeedsLayout, etc.. but none worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still kinda confused by what exactly you're doing, but I think I know what you want to do. You can copy paste the code into a new Xcode project and after a few second you'll see the buttons appear.

```
class ProductDetailView: UIView {
  // The StackView for the buttons should be in this view.
  private lazy var quantitiesStack: UIStackView = {
      let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: self.quantityButtons)
      stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      stack.axis = .horizontal
      stack.distribution = .fillEqually
      stack.spacing = 2.0

      return stack
  }()

  //MARK: - Properties
  var quantityButtons: [UIButton] = [] {
    didSet {
      guard !quantityButtons.isEmpty else { return }

      // Might need to modify this if you update the buttons more than once.
      guard quantitiesStack.arrangedSubviews.isEmpty else { return }

      for button in quantityButtons {
        // Adding these subviews will cause the stackview to be redraw with these buttons.
        quantitiesStack.addArrangedSubview(button)
      }
    }
  }

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
  }

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    commonInit()
  }

  private func commonInit() {
    // layout - this view is basically just a stackview.
    addSubview(quantitiesStack)
    quantitiesStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    quantitiesStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    quantitiesStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    quantitiesStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    quantitiesStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
  }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  let productDetailView = ProductDetailView()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(productDetailView)
    productDetailView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    productDetailView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    productDetailView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    productDetailView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
    productDetailView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true

    // Simulate delay loading data.
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(3), execute: {
      var buttons: [UIButton] = []

      for i in 0..<4 {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.setTitle("Button \(i)", for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.textColor = .black
        buttons.append(button)
      }

      // This will trigger the buttons to be added to the stackView and then they will appear in the UI.
      self.productDetailView.quantityButtons = buttons
    })
  }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!